# Ajax call ok, but form submit still wait

Tags: java, ajax, jsp

my webapp run on browser IEMobile/7.0.
I should avoid viewing the page "page cannot be displayed" when wifi signal is poor.
I've make an ajax call to the server that check the connection and, if ok, the jsp
execute the form submit.
Sometime the call ajax response correctly, but the form submit don't work and, after long wait,
the "page cannot be displayed" is showed.
This is my code

PickingClienteAction.java

```
public ActionForward testConnection(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    // ---------------------------------------
    ActionForward fwd = null;
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0
    response.setDateHeader("Expires", -1); // prevents caching at the proxy server
    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
    // ----------------------------------------

    try {
        String fase = request.getParameter("fase");
        String locaz = request.getParameter("locaz");
        String ipAddr = request.getParameter("ipAddr");
        String codUte = request.getParameter("codUte");
        logger.info("metodo testConnection. fase=" + fase + ", locaz=[" + locaz + "]");
        String upAndRunning = "OK";
        buffer.append(upAndRunning);
        writer.write(buffer.toString());
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        //
        if (locaz != null && !locaz.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            PickingClienteManager pcMan = (PickingClienteManager) getBean("pickingClienteManager");
            pcMan.inserisciLog(ipAddr, fase, locaz, codUte);
        }
        //
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return fwd;
}
```

jsp page

```
<html:html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1" />

    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1">

    <title>Montopolis Terminalini</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/script/SpecialKeysManager.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/script/BrowserManager.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/script/PlaySound.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/script/disableF5.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/script/Tables.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/script/jquery.js" ></script>
    <%@ include file="/WEB-INF/common/activityLogScripts.jsp" %>
<%
    String tipoTerminale = (String) session.getAttribute("TERMINAL_TYPE");
if (tipoTerminale.equalsIgnoreCase("Android") || tipoTerminale.equalsIgnoreCase("TC52") || tipoTerminale.equalsIgnoreCase("MC33")) {
%>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<c:url value='/css/pickingClienteAndroid.css'/>" />
<%
    } else {
%>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<c:url value='/css/pickingCliente.css'/>" />
<%
    }
%>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var nSubmit = 0;
        var error = 'N';
        var locaz = '';

        function someError(errMsg) {
            nSubmit = 0;
            var idErr = document.getElementById("errConn");
            //idErr.innerHTML = '<b><font color="red">' + errMsg + '</font></b>';
            console.log("xhr failed");
            if (locaz == '') {
                locaz = codCor + '.' + codCol + '.' + codPia;
            }
            gestioneLivelli(0);
            Play(2500, 1000,<bean:write name="TERMINAL_VOLUME" />);
        }

        function makeAjaxCallHttp(url, methodType, callback) {
            var codCor = document.getElementById("aCorsia").value;
            var codCol = document.getElementById("aColonna").value;
            var codPia = document.getElementById("aPiano").value;

            //var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                // code for modern browsers
                xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
             } else {
                // code for old IE browsers
                xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }

            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                    clearTimeout(timeout);
                    if (xhr.status === 200) {
                        var resp = xhr.responseText;
                        var respJson = resp; //JSON.parse(resp);
                        callback(respJson);
                    } else {
                        someError('Errore Connessione!');
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log("xhr processing going on");
                }
            }

            xhr.ontimeout = function (e) {
                someError('Timeout!');
            };

            // Impostazione Timeout
            var timeout = setTimeout( function () {  
                xhr.abort(); // invocazione funzione di callback che interrompe la chiamata xhr 
            }, 3000);

            xhr.open(methodType, url, true);
            xhr.timeout = 3000;
            xhr.send();
            console.log("request sent succesfully");
        }

        function checkConnection() {
            if ((nSubmit === 0 && BrowserManager.countSubmit === 0) || error === 'S') {
                nSubmit = 1;

                //##################################################################################
                var fase = document.getElementById("dispatch").value;
                var ipAddr = document.getElementById("nomeTerminale").value;
                var codUte = document.getElementById("codUte").value;
                var action = document.getElementById("dispatch");
                var myUrl = '<c:url value="/pickingCliente.do"/>' + '?dispatch=testConnection&fase='+fase+'&locaz='+locaz+'&ipAddr='+ipAddr+'&codUte='+codUte;
                //##################################################################################

                var idErr = document.getElementById("errConn");
                idErr.innerHTML = '';

                makeAjaxCallHttp(myUrl, "GET", function(respJson){
                    nSubmit = 0;
                    idErr.innerHTML = 'Connessione OK';
                    return BrowserManager.submit();
                });

            }
        }

    </script>

</head>

<body id="theBody" onload="defaultLoad();" onkeydown="keyPressed(event)">

    <div id="errConn">
    </div>

    <!-- Messaggi di errore -->
    <div  id="errore">
    <html:messages id="msg" message="false">
        <font color="red">
            <bean:write name="msg"/>
        </font>
        <script>
        Play(2500, 1000,<bean:write name="TERMINAL_VOLUME" />);
        </script>
    </html:messages>

    <!-- visualizzazione messaggi -->
    <html:messages id="msg" message="true">
        <bean:write name="msg"/>
    </html:messages>
    </div>

    <div id="okConn">
    <tiles:insert attribute="content" />
    </div>

    <table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" width="100%">
        <tr class="TrButtonClass">
            <td>
                <input type="button" class="ButtonClass" value="Indietro" onclick="buttonBack()" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="button" class="ButtonClass" value="Enter" onclick="buttonEnter()" id="enter" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>

</html:html>
```